# Find all the fonts used in a Photoshop file

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop

I have this `.psd` (Photoshop file) and I'm trying to convert it to HTML & CSS.

Only thing I can't determine is what font they used in the `.psd`

How can I find out what fonts were used in the Photoshop file?

Comment: As of CC2018, 2 of the scripts below and the jsx plugin are broken. I commented specifically for each.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Depends on how you want to extract the information.

#### Per section or text area

Select the Text tool (**T** icon with serifs) and click on the text area to edit it. It will show what font is being used in the Character window.

#### All fonts used at a glance

1. Save or export the image document as a PDF
2. Open up the PDF version in Adobe Reader
3. Select File → Properties → Fonts

This will [list all the embeddable fonts used](http://www.clearps.com/photoshop-forum/index.php/t/60551/) in the PSD file, provided you can embed them.

#### Missing fonts

In the Character tool, go to the font selection drop down. At the end of the list will be the fonts that are used in the image but are missing from your system. These will typically be greyed out.

#### Rastersized images

If you see any rasterized images you need the font face of, you'd best export just that section as a clear, standalone image and use a service like [What the Font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to determine the font.

Answer (score 25):

Save this script as a new file in your Photoshop > Presets > Scripts folder.  Name it whatever you want, such as "Detect Fonts.jsx"

```
var p = new ActionReference();

function arrayUnique(a){
    var t = []
        i = a.length;

    while(i--) {
        var f = false,
        n = t.length;

        while (n--) {
            if(a[i] === t[n]) {
                f = true;
            }
        }

        if(!f) {
            t.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return t;
}

function findFonts() {
    p.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );

    var c = executeActionGet(p).getInteger(charIDToTypeID('NmbL'))+1,
        fonts = [];

    while(c--) {
        var r = new ActionReference(),
            descLayer,
            layerStyles,
            countStyles;

        r.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( 'Lyr ' ), c );

        try {
            descLayer = executeActionGet(r);
        } catch (e) {
            continue;
        }

        if(!descLayer.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID( 'textKey' ))) continue;

        layerStyles = descLayer.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('textKey')).getList(stringIDToTypeID('textStyleRange'));
        countStyles = layerStyles.count;

        while(countStyles--) {
            var n = layerStyles.getObjectValue(countStyles).getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('textStyle')).getString(stringIDToTypeID('fontPostScriptName'));
            fonts.push(n);
        }
    }

    return arrayUnique(fonts).sort();
}

if (documents.length) {
    var d = findFonts();
    alert(d.length +' fonts found\n'+d.join('\n'));
} else {
    alert('No fonts used in the active document.',);
}
```

[image]

Comment: +500000 points. Incredible.

Comment: https://github.com/dcondrey/DetectFontsinPSD

Comment: To write text in clipboard use this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13983268/1578857

Comment: (Photoshop CC2018) Error 8500: The requested property does not exist. Line 53: var n = layerStyles.getObjectValue(countStyles).getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('textStyle')).getString(stringIDToTypeID('fontPostScriptName'));

Comment: @Drew I am about to post an updated answer with a fixed version of the script

Answer (score 8):

The PSD file format is [documented](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/) by Adobe - you can read how it stores font information.

You could then examine a hex dump of the file and use the file format specification to find the fonts.

Alternatively, the font names ought to be visible in the output of the `strings`utility found on Linux/Unix systems.

Comment: +1: I came up with the same solution. For some reason GIMP didn't import the PSD correctly and I didn't know which font it was used. I analyzed the PSD file in an HEX editor to find it (Search for: "Font" as TEXT). Recommeded editor: "bless".

Answer (score 6):

This is actually very easy to do using PS scripts, which can iterate through the layers of your PSD and pull text layer data.

I've been experimenting lately with a JavaScript-based script to overlay font information directly on comps that get delivered to developers.  It's not finished but if there's still interest (I see this is quite old) I can put up a quick-and-dirty version that simply pops up the fonts used in a window.

**UPDATE:** I put together a rough but working "lite" version of the script I'm developing. Feel free to contribute - https://github.com/davidklaw/completer. For those unfamiliar with scripts just take the script file and put it under your PS Presets/Scripts folder and it'll be available under File -> Scripts.

Comment: The question might be old, but it has almost 6,000 views. If you could provide a script, that would be very much appreciated! Welcome to Super User, by the way!

Comment: Good call.  Open-source GitHub project is up.  If anyone is familiar with basic JavaScript they should feel right at home.

Comment: wow this actually works pretty good :D (y)!

Answer (score 4):

Quick and Easy Way To Find Missing Fonts

1. Windows -> Character A small character box will display with fonts information.
2. Select font name dropdown and scroll down till end.
3. You will notice list of missing fonts in light grey color at the end of font list.

[image]

From :  http://www.bala-krishna.com/how-to-find-fonts-used-in-psd-file/

Comment: There are numerous ways of enabling that panel: An additional one is Type -> Panels -> Character.

Answer (score 3):

If the text has already been rasterized, the easy way would be to crop the area with the typeface you want to identify, save as a .png and upload it to [**WhatTheFont**](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), where it should be able to tell you what it is, unless it is an obscure or bespoke one.

[**Identifont**](http://www.identifont.com/) is another site you can use, where you describe characteristics of the typeface.

Comment: the text is not rasterized, meaning its in a separate layer.

Comment: @Dave: If the text is still editable, all you have to do is select it and see what appears in the font dropdown menu, or on the information palette.  This is really obvious!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a snap of the text you need (preferably zoomed in) and use [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to get some guesses. (Shouldn't the typeface be shown when you open the PSD and select the respective text, though?)

And of course, if it's not a web-safe font, you'll need to find an appropriate way of replacing it, or providing a fallback stack.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Creative Cloud Extract](http://www.adobe.com/ca/creativecloud/extract.html)

It will list all fonts used (among other handy things).

Comment: Looks like it has some potential, but it requires installing DreamWeaver..

Answer (score 1):

Based on David's original answer (DetectFonts.jsx), I have modified the script to fix the issue reported by Drew in the comments: [Find all the fonts used in a Photoshop file](https://superuser.com/questions/268785/find-all-the-fonts-used-in-a-photoshop-file/907818#comment2057721_907818).

Follow the original instructions but use this script body instead - only difference is a few null checks (presumably either a photoshop version difference or something to do with missing data on particular object types, likely designer or operating system specific)

I will also submit a pull request to https://github.com/dcondrey/DetectFontsinPSD

```
var p = new ActionReference();

function arrayUnique(a) {
    var t = []
    i = a.length;

    while (i--) {
        var f = false,
            n = t.length;

        while (n--) {
            if (a[i] === t[n]) {
                f = true;
            }
        }

        if (!f) {
            t.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return t;
}

function findFonts() {
    p.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));

    var c = executeActionGet(p).getInteger(charIDToTypeID('NmbL')) + 1,
        fonts = [];

    while (c--) {
        var r = new ActionReference(),
            descLayer,
            layerStyles,
            countStyles;

        r.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), c);

        try {
            descLayer = executeActionGet(r);
        } catch (e) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!descLayer.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID('textKey'))) continue;

        layerStyles = descLayer.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('textKey')).getList(stringIDToTypeID('textStyleRange'));
        if(!layerStyles) continue;

        countStyles = layerStyles.count;

        while (countStyles--) {
            var textStyle = layerStyles.getObjectValue(countStyles).getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('textStyle'));
            if(!textStyle || !textStyle.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID('fontPostScriptName'))) continue;

            var n = textStyle.getString(stringIDToTypeID('fontPostScriptName'));
            fonts.push(n);
        }
    }

    return arrayUnique(fonts).sort();
}

if (documents.length) {
    var d = findFonts();
    alert(d.length + ' fonts found\n' + d.join('\n'));
} else {
    alert('No fonts used in the active document.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Photoshop. Go to *Windows » Character*. A small box will pop up. Just select the text layer and the box will tell you the font family, size, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Use online tool to get fonts of psd file

http://psdfonts.com/

Comment: site is not active anymore

Answer (score 0):

Developer asked me almost the same think like you needed. I came up with editing simple script, to export layer properties (text, font name, font size, font color) which you need when developing, to a single txt file (should work on Windows machine).

Just save this like "ExportTexts.js" and put in Adobe Photoshop > Presets > Scripts.

After that, run (or restart) Photoshop and run script (File -> Scripts -> ExportTexts).
Also make sure you ungrouped all layers before doing this.
Exported file should be in a same dir as psd file.

```
if (documents.length > 0)
{
    var docRef = activeDocument;
    CurrentFolder = activeDocument.path;
    var outputFile = new File(CurrentFolder + "/" + activeDocument.name + "fonts.txt" );
    outputFile.open("w");
    for (var i = docRef.layers.length-1 ; i >=0 ; i--)
    {
        docRef.activeLa`enter preformatted text here`yer = docRef.layers[i]
        if (docRef.activeLayer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT)
        {
            outputFile.write( 
            docRef.activeLayer.textItem.contents + "\n" + 
            docRef.activeLayer.textItem.font +"," +
            docRef.activeLayer.textItem.size +"," +
            docRef.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue  + "\n\n\n");
        }
    }
    outputFile.close();
    alert("Finished");
}
else
{
    alert("You must have at least one open document to run this script!");
}
docRef = null
```

Comment: Your script is broken on line 8

Comment: And on line 12. Error 8500, property does not exist: outputFile.write( .

Answer (score 0):

There's a free Photoshop Extension/Panel which can do this job for you, Free Photoshop Font Detector (http://www.layerhero.com/photoshop-font-detector/), and if you want to collect/copy font files from system folder, try Photoshop Art Packer(http://www.layerhero.com/photoshop-art-packer/)

Comment: The "Free Photoshop Font Detector" is no longer available as a free download and is now part of an expensive extension [FontHero for $39](http://www.layerhero.com/fonthero/).

Comment: None of those are available. LayerHero is dead.. Amazingly, you can download Font Detector from the WayBack machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20171211184218/http://www.layerhero.com/photoshop-font-detector/   However I haven't been able to install it, neither with Anastasiy's Extension Manager nor Adobe ExMan.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on the Layers tab that lets you filter all of the layers to show only the fonts. You have to select each layer to actually see them and it is useful only if you need a quick glance at them

Hope it helps someone three years after this was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know document fonts along with their styles, sizes, colors, formatting, etc. for web development and CSS purposes, so here's what I came up with:

1. Click the "T" icon in the Layers panel to filter/view only text layers
2. Shift + left click the topmost text layer in the Layers palette
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom of the Layers palette and Shift + left click the bottom text layer
4. Right click on the selected layers in the Layers palette and choose "Duplicate Layers"
5. Under Destination Document, select New
6. Go to your new document which should contain all of your text layers
7. Select all the layers of text again (see step #2 and #3)
8. Click the folder icon at the bottom of the Layers palette to make all the text layers into one group
9. Change the group's blending mode (the dropdown in the layers palette) to "Normal"
10. Right click your new group
11. Choose "Copy CSS"
12. Paste into a document and format your list of styles as needed!

Answer (score -1):

To get the fonts information form a PSD file you can use online tools if you can't or won't use Photoshop (or if you prefer using Gimp, that rasterizes PSD fonts).

For example you can try out [this html5 PSD font online extractor](http://giovannimuzzolini.com/get-psd-fonts/) "Get PSD Fonts".

It's a PSD font information extractor based on [Melitingice Github project psd.js](http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/) that does not require uploading files, working locally in your browser page

Comment: It opens the file in javascript, without sending it to a server, in your own browser page! You have to drop the file to specify the file path...

Comment: You might want to disclose any affliation you have with the projects mentioned, even if its free.